# AngularJS: Why can't I pass DOM attribute values to the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, swipe

Is it because I'm using `$swipe`?

**HTML**

```
<div start_slide_at="459" slide-controller></div>
```

**JS**

```
myApp.directive('slideController', ['$swipe',
    function($swipe) {

        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                start_slide_at: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.start_slide_at);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

It returns `undefined` right now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can get the value with scope.startSlideAt variable . The "_" or "-" in the DOM attribute is converted to camel casing in the case of angularjs when double binding is used inside the direcitve . So here is your modified link function and scope attribute.

```
     scope: {
                startSlideAt: '='
            },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.startSlideAt);
              }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`=` means two  way binding.

it's need scope variable rather than value

If you wanna just pass value then make scope

```
scope: {
                startSlideAt: '@'
            },
```

And directive convert -,_ camecase

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _

So in link

```
console.log(scope.startSlideAt);
```

Comment: Can you explain this two-way binding a bit more in depth, why use one over the other when both work fine as I tested.